# Can't write greek with newtxtext in XeTeX

Tags: xetex, greek, newtx

I've been trying to use the `newtx` fonts for math and text, and while math seems to work, any text I write in greek won't be displayed. For instance,

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xgreek}

\begin{document}

    Έχουμε ένα φίλτρο Wiener $M$ συντελεστών $\mathbf{w}$ το οποίο έχει ώς είσοδο το σήμα $u(n)$. Ορίζουμε
    $$
    \mathbf{u}(n) = \begin{bmatrix} u(n) & u(n-1) & \ldots u(n-M+1) \end{bmatrix}^\mathrm{T}
    $$
    ως το διάνυσμα πραγμάτωσης των $M$ τελευταίων χρονικών στιγμών της εισόδου $u(n)$ και θα έχουμε $y(n) = \mathbf{w}^\mathrm{H}\, \mathbf{u}(n)$. Οι βέλτιστοι συντελεστές του φίλτρου Wiener δίνονται από τη λύση του συστήματος $\mathbf{R}\, \mathbf{w}_o = \mathbf{p}$, όπου
    $$
    \mathbf{R} = \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf{u}(n)\, \mathbf{u}^\mathrm{H}(n)\right]
    $$

\end{document}
```

produces 
[image: example]
I'm on MacOSX Yosemite, using TeXLive.

Comment: I don't think that NewTX has any support for Greek. Besides, it doesn't make sense to use `newtxtext` along with `polyglossia` and `xgreek`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`newtxtext` doesn't support the Greek language; besides, you're using `fontspec` and XeLaTeX, so `newtxtext` is out of the question to begin with.

Set a Times like text font supporting Greek, for instance Tempora.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xgreek}

\setmainfont{Tempora}

\begin{document}

Έχουμε ένα φίλτρο Wiener $M$ συντελεστών $\mathbf{w}$ το οποίο έχει 
ώς είσοδο το σήμα $u(n)$. Ορίζουμε
\[
\mathbf{u}(n) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
u(n) & u(n-1) & \dots & u(n-M+1)
\end{bmatrix}^\mathrm{T}
\]
ως το διάνυσμα πραγμάτωσης των $M$ τελευταίων χρονικών στιγμών της 
εισόδου $u(n)$ και θα έχουμε $y(n) = \mathbf{w}^\mathrm{H}\, \mathbf{u}(n)$. 
Οι βέλτιστοι συντελεστές του φίλτρου Wiener δίνονται από τη λύση του συστήματος 
$\mathbf{R}\mathbf{w}_o = \mathbf{p}$, όπου
\[
\mathbf{R} = \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{u}(n)\mathbf{u}^\mathrm{H}(n)]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Depending on your TeX distribution and operating system, the call might be different from `\setmainfont{Tempora}`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative, you can use the `XITS` fonts for both math and text.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}% loads fontspec

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=modern]{greek}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{XITS}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}
Έχουμε ένα φίλτρο Wiener $M$ συντελεστών $\mathbf{w}$ το οποίο έχει 
ώς είσοδο το σήμα $u(n)$. Ορίζουμε
\[
\mathbf{u}(n) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
u(n) & u(n-1) & \dots & u(n-M+1)
\end{bmatrix}^\mathrm{T}
\]
ως το διάνυσμα πραγμάτωσης των $M$ τελευταίων χρονικών στιγμών της 
εισόδου $u(n)$ και θα έχουμε $y(n) = \mathbf{w}^\mathrm{H}\, \mathbf{u}(n)$. 
Οι βέλτιστοι συντελεστές του φίλτρου Wiener δίνονται από τη λύση του συστήματος 
$\mathbf{R}\mathbf{w}_o = \mathbf{p}$, όπου
\[
\mathbf{R} = \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{u}(n)\mathbf{u}^\mathrm{H}(n)]
\]
\end{document}
```